# How do I properly instal and import matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, import

I'm facing an issue while trying to import matplotlib 3.3.1. I'm using PyCharm which give me the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>

  File "Y:\7-Python\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\MMK\Miniconda3\envs\env1\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 174, in <module> _check_versions()

  File "C:\Users\MMK\Miniconda3\envs\env1\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 159, in _check_versions from . import ft2font

  File "Y:\7-Python\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing ft2font: Le module spécifié est introuvable.
```

I've been looking on many topics with the same issue about ft2front but none of them gave me a solution that worked. None of them were exactly the same, line error were different. Does anyone already faced a similar error and management to solved it ?
Thanks for your help.

Nicolas

Edit:
I tried to install it in another way: I downloaded the wheel file and installed it. PyCharm is now showing me a different error message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "Y:\7-Python\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\MMK\Miniconda3\envs\env1\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 905, in <module>
    cbook._get_data_path("matplotlibrc"),
  File "C:\Users\MMK\Miniconda3\envs\env1\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 480, in _get_data_path
    return Path(matplotlib.get_data_path(), *args)
AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'get_data_path'
```

I still don't have any idea what this means...

Comment: You should format the error messages as a code block, check out these notes on how to use the markdown functions here, https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Please check out stack overflow formatting help section.  The question need to be edited for formatting.

Comment: Sorry for the use of the wrong format for the error messages. Thanks for the reformating

Answer (score 0):

In PyCharm, go to File --> Settings --> Project --> Project Interpreter
You will see a list of packages, click on the "+" sign at your right and search for matplotlib. Once you find the package just click on "Install Package" [Screenshot for your reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7FPy.png)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately after clicking on "+" the list is empty. I don't have any repository listed yet. When I tried to add the default one: https://pypi.python.org/simple, it didn't work: the list stays empty. I think it's because of my company network configuration. I struggled to be able to download packages from the python terminal, my IT department had to allow me to do it, I guess it is the same here. PyCharm can't be connected to the server...